# Detail views with Collection/Table Views populated with an Array?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsarray, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm having a similar problem in two separate instances, but I feel like the solution for one problem will solve the other.  I'm a noob.  I'm using a Collection View for a photo gallery that I have populated with an NSArray.  The collection view works just fine, and populates the right images in the right order.  I just can't figure out how to get the detail view to work correctly with the code that I have specifically.  I have my delegates set up in the .h file:

```
@interface PhotoViewController : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>
```

The NSArray looks like this:

```
#import "PhotoViewController.h"
#import "PhotoViewCell.h"
#import "ImageDetailController.h"

@interface PhotoViewController ()

@end

@implementation PhotoViewController {

    NSArray *array;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

        array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"walkerthumb.png",@"farmerthumb.png",@"unrulythumb.png",@"fetchthumb.png",@"walkerthumb.png",@"farmerthumb.png",@"unrulythumb.png",@"fetchthumb.png",@"walkerthumb.png",@"farmerthumb.png",@"unrulythumb.png",@"fetchthumb.png",@"walkerthumb.png",@"farmerthumb.png",@"unrulythumb.png",@"fetchthumb.png",@"walkerthumb.png",@"farmerthumb.png",@"unrulythumb.png",@"fetchthumb.png",@"walkerthumb.png",@"farmerthumb.png",@"unrulythumb.png",@"fetchthumb.png", nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.





}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    PhotoViewCell *cell = (PhotoViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [[cell myImageView]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];

    return cell;





}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [array count];


}
```

In my cell's header file, I have the image property called out like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView;
```

I'm trying to push a different detail view based on the image clicked.  I understand it must involve some sort of array again, but I just don't know how to implement it.  I don't know how to tell the Collection View what to do.  None of the tutorials I have tried online have worked.

Comment: Can you show your `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: I don't have that.  Should I?  I basically only have what I posted, which has cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: That is the delegate method that gets invoked when a user selects (taps) one of your collection view cells - so this is typically the method you would use to move to your detail view.

Comment: Alright thank you, I'll have to do some looking on how to implement it, but this points me in the right direction.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the following method to get the click of an 
   item in collection view.
              - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                {
                    //indexPath will return the clicked row index and section.
                }